# I couldnt render the last route in my react app

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

everything renders perfectly except for the last route which is Signup.It even takes me to the SIgnup page where the navbar and background is rendered except for the signup component I dont know if it helps but i added the the signup route some time later than I did the previous ones

heres the code for App.js

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.js"
import {Routes,Router, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import Home from "./components/Home"
import Register from "./components/Register.js";
import Loan from "./components/Loan.js";
import Return from "./components/Return.js";

import React from "react";
import Signup from "./components/Signup.js";
function App() {

  const [loanBooks, setLoanBooks] = React.useState()
  console.log(loanBooks)
  return ( 
    <div>


      <Navbar />
      

        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path='/Register' element={<Register passBook ={book=>setLoanBooks(book)}/>} />
          <Route path='/Loan' element={<Loan bookInfo={loanBooks}/>} />
          <Route path='/Return' element={<Return/>} />
          <Route path='./Signup' element={<Signup/>}/>
        </Routes>


      
      {/* <Signup /> */}
    
    </div>

   
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

and heres the code for Signup.js

```
    import React from 'react'

function Signup() {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
        
            <form className='login-form' action="">
            <h1 className='header'>SIGNUP</h1>
            <hr />
             <div className="mover">
                <input className='login-info' name="fName" type="text" placeholder='First Name' />
                <input className='login-info' name="Lname" type="text" placeholder='Last Name' />
                <input className='login-info' name="Email" type="Email" placeholder='Insert Email' />
                <input className='login-info' name="phoneNo" type="Number" placeholder='Phone no' />
                <input className='login-info' name="password" type="Password" placeholder='Password'/>
                <input className='login-info' name="confirmPassword" type="Password" placeholder='Confirm Password'/>
             </div>
                
                

                <button className='btn'>Sign up</button>
                
            </form>

        

    </div>
  )
}

export default Signup
```

Comment: You've a typo in the route path, `<Route path='./Signup' element={<Signup/>}/>` should be `<Route path='/Signup' element={<Signup/>}/>`, i.e. sans the leading `"."` character. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.` from `./Signup`, so your route should look something like this

```
<Route path='/Signup' element={<Signup/>}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have an extra dot in signup path

```
 <Route path='/Signup' element={<Signup/>}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

because is wrong you should remove . IN SIGNUP LINK AND SHOULD BE LIKE THIS
<Route path='/Signup' element={}/>